# "From now on I will do" vs. "from now on I will be doing"

Tags: difference, future-continuous

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *from now on I will do* and *from now on I will be doing*? For example:

> From now on **I will eat** only healthy food.
>
> From now on **I will be eating** only healthy food.

Answer (score 1):

I think both are correct, the latter puts more stress on the continuity/permanence of your new habit, which is not necessarily needed because you've already got "from now **on**" with "on" doing exactly that.

Comment: I feel like the latter has a little more force, more emphasis on actively, constantly working to make it happen, starting right now!